# How to plot training and validation metrics in same plot every n batches(instead of at epoch end) in tensorboard 2.3 and Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I'm using tensorboard and tensorflow 2.3 and i need to plot training and validation metrics every "n" number of batches in tensorboard, currently i can only plot validation metrics at the end of the epoch(not every "n" batches) and they are shown on different separate plots, i need them to be on the same plot. I've gone through the keras documentation and tensorboard examples and i can't find any parameters to do it in the default tensorboard callback, is there any way to achieve it? do i need to create a custom callback and custom tensorboard  logging rutine? (given it's something so common in ML i think there should be a default way to do it instead of custom, but not sure).